# Run m-type instructions on RISC-V

Tags: c, unix, riscv

Is it possible to run m-type instruction of RISC-V isa from userspace? I have to run `misa` instruction that provides cpu info from a userspace c program, but according to [RISC-V documentation](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Priv-v1.12/riscv-privileged-20211203.pdf) it's possible at machine privilege level. Is it completely impossible or is there a workaround?
I've already tried

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long cpuid()
{
    unsigned long res;
    __asm__ volatile ("csrr %0, misa" : "=r"(res));
    return res;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long mcpuid = cpuid();
    printf("mcpuid: %lu", mcpuid);
    return 0;
}
```

Running it on a RISC-V fedora I get `Illegal instruction`

Comment: Is this *nix as tagged? Then there should be OS provided ways to get cpu info (like reading `/proc/cpuinfo`)

Comment: Yes currently I'm parsing cpuinfo. As far as you know does it contain the same informations of misa (CPUID)?

Comment: I think we all know you're referring to machine level privileged instructions. For MIPS and RISCV, though, the terms around "x"-type instruction usually refers to an instruction format, which goes to the instruction encoding, its fields, as subopcodes and operands (registers and immediates).